# All Devices on Network Being Redirected to Malware Download

Tags: malware, url-redirection

I have a curious problem.

I received a compromised email from an address on my university's domain. 
Not realizing it was faked, I clicked a link in the email to a url on my university's domain, and was then put through to an automatic download of a fake version of Flash. This exec file says it is made by Mandiant. I did some googling, and apparently there is a ransomeware attack that says it is a piece of Mandiant software. I promptly removed the files.

This all makes sense to me. The part that I don't understand is that now **all** of my family's devices (iPhones, android phones, pc and mac laptops) receive the same redirection/download when they hit **any** of my university's domains from any network (tested two different wifi networks and cellular connections so far).

How could this work? The university's system is clearly compromised to some degree. Could they have gotten all of the MAC addresses for devices on my network, and now be rerouting traffic based on this?

I should also note that a friend of mine has no issue accessing any of the university domains. He has had no exposure to my network.

Comment: You are confused. Mandiant is a reputable cybersecurity company.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect that the exe file claimed to be from Mandiant. Given the context of the download and the fact that it calls itself an Adobe Flashplayer update, I highly doubt that this is legit.

Any input on what's going on here?

Comment: check on the devices which DNS they are using, and try to set it to 8.8.8.8 (google). if the problem goes away, the set you to a bad DNS.

Comment: Interesting. I set my system to the google DNS and I still get redirected to the download page but now I receive a 404 Error page from my university saying that the requested page could not be found. Could the original redirect be in a bash file or something?

Comment: Wait.... so did you actually execute the fake Flash install?  Or did you  delete the download without ever opening it ?  Cause I'm wondering whether the issue is simply a flat-out (partial) compromise of the university's network infrastructure, with traffic from some sources going through compromised elements and being redirected while traffic from other sources avoids those compromised portions. (I'm not a network engineer; excuse my lack of precision in terminology.) Instead of some malware issue on your device/s or such.

Comment: Of course, if you haven't already I'd immediately alert your university's appropriate IT department.  Both to possibly gain some light on whether your devices have been compromised or the malicious behavior is due entirely to compromised university systems, and to possibly help spare less tech savvy users at your institution from installing malware.

Comment: how are the family devices connected to each other? Are they using the same Google account or a specific browser? Did you try to access from a different wifi?

Comment: @halinformed: I did not execute the file  I emailed the web master yesterday, and it turns out that the university's DNS got hacked and was rerouting traffic at random, it just happened that every time I checked, my browser got rerouted. The issue has resolved now. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You may want to contact the university IT support if there is a potential they are compromised. They may also have a fix or solution as the attacker probably also targeted other people in the community. At the very least you can help others from being attacked as well.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to answer the question and accept your own answer. No point leaving it open if the problem has been solved.